# Nested model size is bigger(+1) than used to be in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to understand a problem I have encountered in some of my Rails projects. I have two models,

First one:

```
class Donkey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, :surname, :age, presence: true 
end
```

Second one:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :donkey

  validates :comment, :commenter, presence: true
end
```

My problem is before I add a record to Comment model, the @donkey.comments.size is 1 and the returning object is nil.

To escape from this I am using,

```
<% @donkey.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p><strong><%= comment.commenter %></strong></p>
    <p><%= comment.comment %></p>

    <% if comment.id.present? %>

    <p><%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', donkey_comment_path(@donkey, comment),
                method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Do you really want to delete this question?' } %></p>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Above code in my view file, if you pay attention you can see I am using if statement not to get an error. (nil object)

My 'adding comment' code from view file in below,

```
<%= form_for([@donkey, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.label :commenter %>: <%= f.text_field :commenter %></p>
  <p><%= f.label :comment %>: <%= f.text_area :comment %></p>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And @comment = @donkey.comments.build in my controller.

I am trying to understand this error, thats why I made a simple model like this. I am checking SQL server there is no record in it but @donkey.comments.size is 1 with a nil object.

Anyone can help me on this issue?

Thank you very much for your time,

Comment: Have you tried creating a Donkey and comments in console to isolate if the problem is in the model?

Comment: Thanks for your response @rockskull . I destroyed development database and migrated again and logged to rails console and created Donkey and Comment records from there => the result is there is one record but the size is 2. What can be the problem in model? It is simple you can see above.. Really curious :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you would `build` a comment in your controller is so you have access to it in your view and it is then sent with the form on submit.

This is a common pattern if you are using `form.fields_for` in your view to get access to a relation to the main object you are trying to create in that form. In your case the `@donkey` would be your main object and you would get access to one `comment` in your view, which you can iterate over `@donkey.comments` and you will always get at least one to display.

The problem is that you are adding your non-persisted comment to the `@donkey.comments` list and it doesn't yet have an `id` so when you refer to it here

`donkey_comment_path(@donkey, comment)`

everything explodes.

So you are doing the correct thing in checking if it has and id first here

`<% if comment.id.present? %>`

but the more "Rails Way" would be to either

`<% if comment.persisted? %>`

or

`<% unless comment.new_record? %>`

> notice the `unless` above

See here for the API for this stuff http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F

Hope this doesn't make it even more complicated ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, I found the error at the end but I think creating a new empty comment in controller must not be mixed with previous recorded objects. Thanks for sharing Rails way approach with me :)

Answer (score 0):

open rails console, and try this and find what is going on

```
> @donkey = Donkey.find(1)
> @donkey.comments
> @donkey.comments.inspect
> @donkey.comments.size
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Rails console gives, irb(main):004:0> @donkey.comments.size => 0 but in view it still shows size as 1, so strange :(

Comment: ok, do you use any debug tools/gems viz. pry-rails, pry-byebug?
Or RubyMine's debugging tool?
If yes the you could use binding.pry (put break point) and see whats going on there

Answer (score 0):

It is so strange,

When I removed

```
@comment = @donkey.comments.build
```

from DonkeyController and change <%= form_for from ([@donkey, @comment]) do |f| %> to,

```
form_for([@donkey, @donkey.comments.build]) do |f|
```

the error dissapeared.

Do you think I need to open a bug ticket for this or am I doing something wrong by declaring @comment inside controller.